# How to fill a table with an object including an array of object in Angular2

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm currently programming in Angular2/Typescript and I'm blocked with a table. I want to fill a table with the information I receive from my service which looks like that :

```html
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "serviceWindow": "24/7",
  "status": "Active",
  "customer": "BGL",
  "serviceProvidedType": "Call Desk",
  "drpContactList": [
   {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Jean Bon",
    "timeStart": "08:00",
    "timeEnd": "16:00",
    "value": "jean.bon@ctg.com",
    "mediumType": "Email"
   },
   {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Charles Degaule",
    "timeStart": "16:00",
    "timeEnd": "19:00",
    "value": "+352 258 484 494",
    "mediumType": "SMS"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "serviceWindow": "Week-end",
  "status": "Active",
  "customer": "POST",
  "serviceProvidedType": "Monitoring",
  "drpContactList": [
   {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Michel Palmas",
    "timeStart": "10:00",
    "timeEnd": "15:00",
    "value": "+352 658 194 191",
    "mediumType": "Phone"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "serviceWindow": "Business hours",
  "status": "Active",
  "customer": "ING",
  "serviceProvidedType": "Sharepoint",
  "drpContactList": [
   {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Alex Lapage",
    "timeStart": "05:00",
    "timeEnd": "10:00",
    "value": "alex.lapage@ctg.com",
    "mediumType": "Email"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 4,
  "serviceWindow": "Manage services",
  "status": "Active",
  "customer": "DEXIA",
  "serviceProvidedType": "System Admin",
  "drpContactList": [
   {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Rémi Hirtz",
    "timeStart": "19:30",
    "timeEnd": "23:00",
    "value": "+352 595 945 154",
    "mediumType": "Phone"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 5,
  "serviceWindow": "Enterprise holiday",
  "status": "Active",
  "customer": "POST",
  "serviceProvidedType": "Hands & Eyes",
  "drpContactList": [
   {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Thomas Jacobs",
    "timeStart": "13:00",
    "timeEnd": "18:30",
    "value": "thomas.jacbos@ctg.com",
    "mediumType": "Email"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 6,
  "serviceWindow": "24/7",
  "status": "Active",
  "customer": "BGL",
  "serviceProvidedType": "IT Outsourcing",
  "drpContactList": [
   {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Adrien Lafonte",
    "timeStart": "05:45",
    "timeEnd": "10:30",
    "value": "+352 151 615 842",
    "mediumType": "SMS"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

So there is an array of object in my principal object. How can I display the information of the second array ? I tried some tricks but I never found a good way. Here is my HTML and Typescript :

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
            <th style="width:150px" align="center">Customer</th>
            <th style="width:150px" align="center">Service provided</th>
            <th style="width:150px" align="center">Service window</th>
            <th style="width:150px" align="center">DRP contact name</th>
            <th style="width:150px" align="center">Time Start</th>
            <th style="width:150px" align="center">Time End</th>
            <th style="width:150px" align="center">Medium</th>
            <th style="width:150px" align="center">DRP contact address</th>
            <th style="width:150px" align="center">Status</th>

            <tr *ngFor="#drp of drps"
                [class.selected]="drp === selectedDrp"
                (click)="gotoEdit(drp)">

                <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.customer}}</td>
                <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.serviceProvidedType}}</td>
                <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.serviceWindow}}</td>
                <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.drpContactList[0].name}}</td>
                <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.drpContactList[0].timeStart}}</td>
                <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.drpContactList[0].timeEnd}}</td>
                <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.drpContactList[0].mediumType}}</td>
                <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.drpContactList[0].value}}</td>
                <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.status}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

As you can see, for the moment I only show the first objet in the array. Either I put everything in only one row or I can create as row as object in the array.

Here is the Typescript behind everything :

```html
export class ListDrpsComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
    drps:Drp[];

    constructor(private _drpService:DrpService,
                private messageService:MessageToUserService,
                private _router:Router) {
        super(_router, messageService);
    }

    onAddDrp() {
        let link = ['AddDrp'];
        this._router.navigate(link);
    }
    
    getDrps() {
        this._drpService.getDrps().subscribe(
            data => {
                this.onNext(data)
            },
            (data)=> this.onError(data),
            () => null
        );
    }

    onNext(data:Response) {
        super.onNext(data);
        this.drps = <Drp[]> data.json();
        console.log(this.drps);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getDrps();
    }

    onError(data:Response) {
        super.onError(data);
    }

    gotoEdit(drp:Drp) {
        let link = ['EditDrp', {id: drp.id}];
        this._router.navigate(link);
    }
    
    
}
```

I'm sorry for the presentation of the code, I'm new here ! If you need more details, tell me, I will try to respond to your demand. And sorry for my English, it's not my native language, I'm still learning.

Cordially,

Florian

EDIT : Here is a picture of what the table looks like. I wanted to have one row per information if possible (so i should repeat the first object information as many times as there is object in the second array)

[Table of DRP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMM5G.png)

Comment: Why don't you implement an additional nested ngFor for the sub-array?

Comment: What's the question here ? How to do it or how should it look like ? You didn't provide how do you expect to display your table to look like. 
I made this : https://plnkr.co/edit/MUr9qFQrWDtNJTXkMPcp?p=preview but I don't now if it answers your question

Comment: (PS : "Jean Bon" sounds like a delicious name)

Comment: Because I don't see how I could do it. I thought about doing a model specially for the list ?

Comment: @YounesM That's how I want it to look ! I will try to figure out how to not repeat the title of the column.

Comment: I made an edit to show you my table ! You have the idea @YounesM, but if possible, i want to keep the table as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without modifying your model ([plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BpkHmWztMuGwjFk5GIZT?p=preview)):

```
<ng-template ngFor let-drp [ngForOf]="drps">
    <tr *ngFor="let drpCt of drp.drpContactList"
        [class.selected]="drp === selectedDrp"
        (click)="gotoEdit(drp)">

        <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.customer}}</td>
        <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.serviceProvidedType}}</td>
        <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.serviceWindow}}</td>

        <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drpCt.name}}</td>
        <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drpCt.timeStart}}</td>
        <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drpCt.timeEnd}}</td>
        <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drpCt.mediumType}}</td>
        <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drpCt.value}}</td>

        <td style="width:150px" align="center">{{drp.status}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, needed to make some changes, but it display nothing :S <ng-template *ngFor let-drp [ngForOf]="drps">
                <tr *ngFor="#drpCt of drp.drpContactList"
                [class.selected]="drp === selectedDrp"
                (click)="gotoEdit(drp)">